# How to get video thumbnail from file or content Uri?

Tags: android, uri, video-thumbnails

I have tried:

```
ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(uri.getPath(),
 MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

But this returns null for a content `Uri`. I have also tried this:

```
private Bitmap getVideoThumbnail(Context context, Uri uri) throws IllegalArgumentException,
        SecurityException{
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(context,uri);
    return retriever.getFrameAtTime();
}
```

This works for both file scheme and content scheme `Uri`s. But it takes ~1.5s to get thumbnail of content `Uri`s representing remote data blocking the UI. I suppose I could make this async and receive the thumbnail is a callback. But I thought there must be a simpler approach to get thumbnails for both file and content `Uri`s. Also this method throws `IllegalArgumentException`s sporadically.

So, is there a way to reliably get thumbnail from file or content `Uri` schemes?

Comment: "I suppose I could make this async and receive the thumbnail is a callback" -- even simpler is to use an image-loading library like Picasso, which can handle all of that for you, given the video's `Uri`.

Comment: Try it, if it helps change Thumbnails.MINI_KIND to Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried loading into `imageView` using: `Picasso.with(context).load(videoUri).into(imageView);` (Also tried `videoUri.toString()`). It wasn't failing/throwing any exception/warning. But no thumbnail was loaded. This is how you meant it to be done right?

Comment: @VeneetReddy: Yes, assuming that the `videoUri` represents a `Uri` to the actual video. `videoUri=ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, id);`, where `id` is the ID of the video (e.g., from `MediaStore.Video.Media._ID`). [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.5/RecyclerView/VideoList) has some flaws (I don't think I should be using the `DATA` column), but it demonstrates the technique and works.